# Ansible - Playbook returning error on bash command

Tags: bash, ansible

I am running a bash command using Ansible.

```
kubectl version  | head -1 | awk '{print $5}'| cut -d"\"" -f2
```

The output is supposed to be

```
   v1.2.0
```

Playbook is ::

```
   - name: version of minion before upgrade.
     command: 'kubectl version  | head -1 | awk '{print $5}'| cut -d"\"" -f2'


     register: version
```

I have also used

```
     command: "kubectl version  | head -1 | awk '{print $5}'| cut -d"\"" -f2"
```

But it keeps returning me the ERROR.

```
# ansible-playbook upgrade_k8s.yaml -i ../env/platform
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/root/ejusnub/ansible/playbook/upgrade_k8s.yaml': line 40, column 50, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

   - name: version of minion before upgrade.
     command: 'kubectl version  | head -1 | awk '{print $5}'| cut -d"\"" -f2'
                                                 ^ here
```

Ive even tried to escape every symbol but the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you can use `kubectl version` with the `--short` parameter whose purpose is to get the version number, here it is in a shell task:

```
 - shell: 'kubectl version --short | cut -d: -f2'
```

This will remove the need for the calls to `head` and `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- shell: kubectl version | head -1 | awk '{ print $5 }' | cut -d'"' -f2
```

Use `shell` module instead of `command` to work with pipes.

P.S. and carefully read error messages, in every case in your example (with single quotes and with double quotes), you have misplaced quotes.